# Is it possible to combine DevExpress MVC Extensions with DexExtreme components in standard MVC application?

Tags: devexpress-mvc

We should make a decision in our company what architecture to use in new web project. We've already successfully used DevExpress' WPF components and thinking of buying their web products, but don't have enough experience with them. So, the next question is for people who have some experience with DevExpress' web components.

Could we start the solution as standard MVC project built in VS 2013 and then add DevExpress' MVC extensions such as data grid etc. and DevExtreme components (jQuery or AngularJS) as well? If we can do that, could you explain, please, what could be possible difficulties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it isn't a good idea to mix up server-side DevExpress Mvc Extensions and client-side DevExtreme Widgets. If you are comfortable with asp.net mvc and want to use client-side javascript technologies, look at [DevExtreme Mvc Wrappers](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/ASP.NET_MVC_Wrappers/Fundamentals/).

It supports a convenient razor syntax to configure widgets. And you can use javascript to handle events, implement client-side templates etc.

To see how it works in action, refer [DevExtreme demos](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Data_Grid/WebAPIService/Mvc/Light/).

Comment: In the meantime I've got the answer from DevExpress: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T499024